# How does the "AND" operator work when search using an index?

Tags: sql, database-indexes

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE owner="abc" AND status="public"
```

where both `owner` and `status` have an index.

The clause `WHERE owner="abc"` may using index with **B-tree** to search the posts where the `owner` is equal to `abc` efficiently(correct me if I'm wrong).

But it won't stop there, it should further looking up for the `AND status="public"` condition too, my question is that how does the DB engine do this additional lookup efficiently? or maybe it'll just does a full scan on the result set of `WHERE owner="abc"` ?

I'm curious about how does the DB engine handle such queries like this efficiently.

Comment: [how mysql uses indexed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).  MySQL and probably others would expect a composite index to utilize this properly.  You can't really use two separate indexes very well.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 3):

In your case,  MySQL (or any other modern database) will use just one index.

Imagine that you have a book, where you have two indexes: one by chapters, at the beginning of the book and one by keyword, usually at the end.

It is easy for you to find the page for chapter 3, and it is easy for you to find the pages for the keyword "recursion". However, if you need to find the pages for recursion inside chapter 3, the two different indexes separated don't really help.

The database works like this - they have an ordered set for each index, referencing the rows. However, for a given user, there is not indexing/sorting based on other columns.

The answer, as people pointed in comments, is an index composed of more than one column. In your case, you would have:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON posts (owner, status);
```

In this case, you are telling the database to create an index sorted by owner, and within the same owner sorted by status. So now you have what your query needs - an index that filters by both columns.

You could also look for the [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html#explain-execution-plan) command. In this case, you ask for the database on how it is planning the execution of your query: which indexes will be used, for example.

Comment: I like your example.